# Почему вопрос ещё открыт?

Tags: поддержка, вопросы, тревоги

Я отмечал этот [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/483952/%D0%92-%D0%BA%D0%B0%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%B8%D0%B7-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D1%83%D1%85-%D1%81%D0%BB%D1%83%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B5%D0%B2-mongodb-%D0%B1%D1%83%D0%B4%D0%B5%D1%82-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%B5) тревогой: «необходимо переформулировать вопрос так, чтобы можно было дать объективно верный ответ».

Модератор отметил тревогу полезной, но вопрос ещё открыт.

Почему?

Comment: Вот история проверок этого вопроса: http://ru.stackoverflow.com/review/close/56073

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Тревоги типа "должен быть закрыт" обрабатываются не модераторами (точнее, не только ими).

Установка такой тревоги забрасывает вопрос в очередь [Голосов за закрытие](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/review).

Доступ к этой очереди есть у участников с привилегией [Открывать и Закрывать](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), т.е. у всех пользователей с 3000+ репутации.

Если при просмотре очереди участник решает, что вопрос стоит закрыть - он отдает за это голос. При наборе 5 голосов вопрос закрывается. Но тревога помечается полезной уже после первого полученного голоса.

Т.е. "полезность" в этом случае означает, что после установки тревоги вопрос начали закрывать. Но не означает, что вопрос на самом деле закрыли, и что его вообще закроют.